# Опасности использования самосозданных сертификатов в службах WCF

Tags: wcf, сертификат

Привет, хочу удостоверять свой сервис, написанный с использованием WCF на .NET, при помощи  X.509 сертификата. 
Во время разработки создавал и использовал сертификаты при помощи утилиты makecert:

1) самоподписанный "корневой" сертификат, 
2) сертификат подписанный "корневым"

Сервис использует второй сертификат, а корневой, для успешной валидации, должен быть установлен у клиентов.

Вопрос: могу ли я использовать такой подход "на производстве". Какие недостатки (кроме установки корневого у клиентов) имеют самосозданные сертификаты относительно сертификатов созданных и купленных в центрах сертификации.

Comment: Вопрос: могу ли я использовать такой подход "на производстве".
 - можете.

Когда сертификат выдает крупный центр по выдачи таких сертификатов они проверяют вас (проверят инфу об организации, кто зарегистрировал домен и т.п.) и регистрирую инфу так скажем в каталоге доверительных сайтов.. Очень много плюсов..